# In a touch event, determine which subview was touched

Tags: ios, xcode5, gesture, touch-event

I have a view controller with a number of subviews. When user clicks on the screen, I want to know which child view was touched. Is there a way to determine this?

```
-(void)touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
    UIView *touchedView = ...
    if(touchedView == self.importantView){
      //do something cool.
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out what view a touch event ended at?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328875/how-to-find-out-what-view-a-touch-event-ended-at)

Comment: besides implementing `touchesBegan` in my UIViewController is there anything more that I need to do? The method is never called. Not even once, and I have NSLog. In storyboard and in code I set `userInteractionEnabled = YES`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
UIView *touchView = touch.view;
```