# How to get the UIView object at the location of UITouch from - (void)touchesEnded:withEvent:?

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, uitouch, uiresponder, touchesended

I want to get the object at the location of where the touch is lifted (off the screen).

This will be used to implement a drag-and-drop and I have these methods for overriding:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Using `[[touches anyObject] view]` in touchesEnded:withEvent: gives me the UIView object of where I first touched but not where I released my touch.

Using  `[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view]` does give me the location of where the touch was released but I would have to map the coordinates to UIView.

Comment: May be this will help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328875/how-to-find-out-what-view-a-touch-event-ended-at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328875/how-to-find-out-what-view-a-touch-event-ended-at)

Comment: @Ronak Chaniyara AH. Thank you. I couldn't find it anywhere; I guess I was just googling the wrong words.

Comment: Great you fixed it!@David

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was answered in a different question worded differently.

Answered by @Ronak Chaniyara: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16329436/3920809